# While Loop and insert into Array, plus display input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

In my main method, I have the following:

```
String myArr[] = new String[10];
    int myTries = 10;
    int myInput = 0;
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String scanInput;

    while(myInput < myTries){

        System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
        scanInput = myScan.next();
        //myArr[myInput] = scanInput;
        myInput++;
    }
```

I am looking to ask the user to insert a value 10 times. Once they inserted it 10 times, it will display their input in order and then in reverse.

I am having an issue storing that information in the array. As you can see, I commented that part out. So far, it asks the user exactly 10 times to enter a value, and then nothing else. Pointers will be great.

This has to stay as a while loop, I will have to re-code as a for loop after.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you should put the part that stores it in the array back. Then you should add a second loop.

Comment: And the issue is...?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Am i storing it correctly?

Comment: @immibis so it works like I said, but lets say I add a System.out.print(myArr) I get a weird error code in eclipse.

Comment: @newJavaCoder your question is "how do I print the contents of an array?" then, because System.out.print(myArr) doesn't do what you'd expect.

Comment: @newJavaCoder it's not that complicated. your myArr[myInput] = ... is perfect. You simply need to call myScan.nextLine() not myScan.next(). nextLine() takes the whole line and moves on the next line while next() just takes the next word (whenever there is a space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some extra variables, you can do the work you want with:

```
    int[] myArr = new int[10];
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);        

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
        myArr[i] = myScan.nextInt();
        myScan.nextLine(); // you need it to consume the "enter"
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArr)); // will print the array
```

Comment: Thanks @alfasin - but for now I need a while loop.

Comment: @newJavaCoder you can do the same with a while loop

Comment: @alfasin they were pretty specific about the while loop. It doesn't make sense, but we should respect the question.

Comment: @lacraig2 for loops makes more sense, totally agree with you. I am just trying to work through this and understand as I go. :)

Comment: @newJavaCoder while and for loop are equivalent and can be translated easily from one to the other.